# How to restrict a for-each loop with some condition using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this XML code and I want my for loop to run/display only values for specific type num- 10,20,180

```
<input>
<name>Jack</name>
<age>23</age>
<type-10-num>1</type-10-num>
<type-20-num>2</type-20-num>
<type-20-char>3</type-20-char>
<type-180-num>4</type-180-num>
<type-180-char>5</type-180-char>
<type-180-str>6</type-180-str>
</input>
```

I'm running a for-each loop for checking the type node-

```
<xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($input)/*[starts-with(name(),'type-')]">
```

And fetching the type value from it in a variable-

```
 <xsl:variable name="fetchValue">               
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(name(), '-'), '-')" />                   
                    </xsl:variable>
```

But I want my for loop to run one time for each values 10,20,180.
If type-20 occurs 2 times I want it to run one time for each 20 and then go to next 180. So total it should run 3 times or lets just say I want to print some details related to these 3 values (so it should not repeat).

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match=
        "*[starts-with(name(), 'type-')
         and substring(name(), string-length(name())-2) = 'num'
         ]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (formatted for readability):

```
<input>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <type-10-num>1</type-10-num>
    <type-20-num>2</type-20-num>
    <type-20-char>3</type-20-char>
    <type-180-num>4</type-180-num>
    <type-180-char>5</type-180-char>
    <type-180-str>6</type-180-str>
</input>
```

**Produces data for each of the elements with name** type-XYZ-num:

```
<type-10-num>1</type-10-num>
<type-20-num>2</type-20-num>
<type-180-num>4</type-180-num>
```

**One can replace this code in the matching template:**

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

with whatever is necessary in the particular problem being solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring-after` two times to check for an ending `num`. A separate variable is not necessary.

```
<xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($input)/*[starts-with(name(),'type-') and substring-after(substring-after(name(),'-'),'-') = 'num']">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Output is:**

```
1 2 4
```

---

If you want to match only these exact names, you could select them directly:

```
<xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($input)/*[self::type-10-num or self::type-20-num or self::type-180-num]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output is the same.